# Can't convert from BSON type array to string exception in MongoDB aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I get this exception from Mongodb aggregation operation:

I need to show in the aggregation and this is what it looks like in the base of mongodb

[image]

cannot convert from BSON type string to date (16006)).

```
  {
    _id: { $substr: ["$gateway.reverse.errors.message", 0, 500] },
    acum: {
        $sum: 1
    }
  }
```

They help me?

Thanks you